# How do I write a gherkin specification to check a large list of values?

Tags: cucumber, bdd, gherkin

I'm working to write a specification with gherkin (for the first time) for a REST API which will return a long list of paged items (1000 items per page). I'm curious if there's a good way in gherkin to write a specification such as this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is i one of the requirements that it limits results too 1000 items pretty page, or do you just want to submit a query and verify results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I belive such the verification will contradict the goal of Gherkin to improve readability of your scenarios. However if I would approach such the task, I would keep the item list in a separate source (say, a file). And then  the construction like:

```
Given I am at the page with a long list
When Check all the items on a page
Then List items correspond to file "C:/MyPath/goldensource.txt"
```

Then you develop your step definition code to read from specified file and compare the result.

Comment: I'm not a QA developer myself, so this is a bit out of my zone. Would you recommend this sort of testing happen in a different manner?